# Make PHP and Nginx Docker images work together

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I tried many many advises, but can't make it working.
I want to create a `docker-compose.yml` file with `NGINX-PHP` cooperation.

Here's what I made:

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - php
    depends_on:
      - php
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
      - ./config/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
      - ./config/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

  php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
```

`Docker` images run without errors, but when I want to access `Nginx`, I get this:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

I tried to log into both images and check volumes. I also checked if I can ping `php` from `nginx`. Everything seems to be fine...

Here's my `Nginx` site configuration:

```
server {
    server_name ncp-docker;

    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /(inc|uploads/avatars) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but you may want to update to compose version 3, which is the current version https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defaulting to default server configuration, so you need to overwrite the default nginx virtual host:

```
    - ./config/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Use that and remove both sites-enabled and sites-available volumes

Answer (score 2):

i think you might be approaching this incorrectly.

the nginx configuration should not be running PHP directly. PHP is running on a separate container.

instead, you should have nginx reverse proxy to the PHP app.

something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://php:9000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
 }
```

there's probably some detail you need to add / change... but this is the basic reverse proxy that i cut & paste when i need it, in nginx

Comment: The port 9000 is not an HTTP port, it's CGI communication, so you cannot proxy_pass to it. Because of that he implements fastcgi_pass.

Comment: ah - the details of php that i can never remember :) thanks @Robert!

Answer (score 1):

As Robert suggested you have to overwrite the default nginx virtual host, however, I would like to add that you can also add an extra Dockerfile for your nginx container and avoid using volumes. In your `docker-compose.yml` you have to change `image: nginx:latest` with `build: ./nginx/`. For the Dockerfile something like this should do the trick:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/  #Replace the default nginx virtual host
```

I find this easier as later on you can easily add more things to the container for example SSL certificates for a HTTPS connection:

```
ADD ssl/ /etc/nginx/ssl/
```

This will save you using volumes and will make your life easier for future nginx settings.